# Why is XSLT transformation outputing dates? XML is SOAP response

Tags: xml, xslt

Does anyone know why would XSLT transformation add something to the output (html) that's not in the XSL template?

Check my example below, I'm trying to get rid of the dates (see output).

**xsl template**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/Common.Akol"
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
<!-- Edited by Adrian -->

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="GetDriverDataResult">

<hr />

trans key:
<xsl:value-of select="a:driverInformationResponse/a:TransKey" />

trans key 2:
<xsl:value-of select="a:driverInformationResponse/a:TransKey" />

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2014-08-27T00:29:39.204Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2014-08-27T00:34:39.204Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetDriverDataResponse>
      <GetDriverDataResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/Common.Akol" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:driverInformationResponse>
          <a:TransKey>C00029540</a:TransKey>
          <a:Status>Success</a:Status>
        </a:driverInformationResponse>
      </GetDriverDataResult>
    </GetDriverDataResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**OUPUT**

```
2014-08-27T00:29:39.204Z
2014-08-27T00:34:39.204Z


trans key:
C00029540

trans key 2:
C00029540
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By default, text nodes are copied to the output XML document by the [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule).**

To suppress this behavior, add this template to match text nodes and do nothing with them:

```
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

Comment: Just wondering for future reference, how did you know it's text node?
Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: You're welcome.  The dates are clearly text; they're not elements, attributes, comments, or processing-instructions.